# How to simulate mouse click on specific virtual keyboard button?

Tags: delphi, button, keyboard, mouse, virtual

There is a form with a virtual keyboard. I'd like to simulate a mouse click on a specific virtual keyboard button when a user clicks on REAL keyboard button. I want to achieve that for 2 reasons:

1. I plan to have a modifier button on my virtual keyboard that I want to be affected with the real button down and up presses.
2. The painting effect on the virtual keyboard when pressing the real keyboard.

So, I have some code that after pressing real keyboard button "A" seems to successfully clicks virtual "A" button, but it does not work properly all the way.

```
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    TouchKeyboard1: TTouchKeyboard;
  private
    { Private declarations }
  protected
    procedure WndProc(var Message: TMessage); override;
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;
  TCastTouchKeyboard= class(TTouchKeyboard);
var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation
{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.WndProc(var Message: TMessage);
 var
  MouseLDownMsg: TWMMButtonDown;
begin
  inherited;                          {ScanCode of letter A}
  if (Message.Msg = WM_KEYDOWN) and (Lo(Message.lParamHi) = $1E) then
  with MouseLDownMsg, TCastTouchKeyboard(TouchKeyboard1) do
   begin
    Msg:= WM_LBUTTONDOWN;
    Pos:= PointToSmallPoint(Buttons[31].BoundsRect.CenterPoint);
    WndProc(TMessage(MouseLDownMsg))
   end
end;
end.
```

I'd appreciate any advice about general idea to process key down and up presses on real keyboard with appropriate mouse clicks on virtual keyboard.

Comment: [You can't simulate keyboard input with PostMessage](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050530-11/?p=35513) It is equally troublesome whether you are using mouse messages or keyboard messages, `SendMessage()` or `PostMessage()` or `WndProc()`, etc. The *correct* and *official* way to simulate user input is to use [`SendInput()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-sendinput) instead

Answer (score 0):

You are right Remy. Here is the code:

```
procedure TForm1.WndProc(var Message: TMessage);
 var
  Input: TInput;
  Point: TPoint;
begin
  inherited;
  with Input, Point, TCastTouchKeyboard(TouchKeyboard1), Message do
  if (Msg = WM_KEYDOWN) and (LParamHi = $1E) and (Buttons[31].State <> TCustomKeyboardButton.TDrawState.dsPressed) then
   begin
    Point:= TouchKeyboard1.ClientToScreen(Buttons[31].BoundsRect.CenterPoint);
    X:= Round(X / GetSystemMetricsForWindow(SM_CXSCREEN, Handle) * Succ(High(Word)));
    Y:= Round(Y / GetSystemMetricsForWindow(SM_CYSCREEN, Handle) * Succ(High(Word)));
    Itype:= INPUT_MOUSE;
    with mi do begin
      dx:= X;
      dy:= Y;
      mouseData:= 0;
      dwFlags:= MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE or MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE;
      time:= 0;
      dwExtraInfo:= 0;
      SendInput(1, Input, SizeOf(TInput));
      dwFlags:= MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN;
      SendInput(1, Input, SizeOf(TInput));
      dwFlags:= MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP;
      SendInput(1, Input, SizeOf(TInput))
    end
   end
end;
```

Thanks

Comment: FYI, it is almost always a *bug* to call `SendInput()` with `cInputs=1`, especially when there are no delays in between events.  In this example, you should put your inputs into an array instead and then call `SendInput()` 1 time with `cInputs=3` instead. That ensures all of the events are put into the input queue atomically.

Comment: That is very important notification. Thx!